# Get the student result from status when grouping in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have created a temporary table from records which looks like below. I want to group student using student id (stu_D). While grouping student result status will be PASSED if he passed all the subject and FAILED if he failed at least one.thanks in advanced

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query -

```
 SELECT stu_D
   ,stuName
   ,CASE 
    WHEN T2.CNT = 0 
         THEN 'passed' 
         ELSE 'failed' 
    END status 
FROM (SELECT stu_D
            ,stuName
            ,COUNT(CASE
                   WHEN result = 'FAILED' 
                       THEN 1
                   END) CNT
     FROM T
     GROUP BY stu_D
             ,stuname) T2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   T.stu_D, T.stuName, IF(T.number_of_failures>0, 'FAILED', 'PASSED') final_result
FROM
(SELECT 
   stu_D, stuName, COUNT(IF(result='FAILED', 1, NULL)) number_of_failures
 FROM your_table
 GROUP BY stu_D, stuName) T;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
 SELECT stu_Name,result
    FROM `marks`
    WHERE stu_D not in
    (SELECT stu_D FROM marks WHERE  result='FAILED')
    GROUP BY stu_D
```